# Language setting isn't respected on URL field of biblatex reference

Tags: biblatex, biber, urls

I am currently writing my thesis in Greek, but I have to cite mostly English sources. My bibliography file looks like this:

```
@online{microsoft-memory-safety-errors,
    author={\en{MSRC Team}},
    title={\en{A proactive approach to more secure code}},
    url={\en{https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2019/07/16/a-proactive-approach-to-more-secure-code/}},
    year={2019},
    month={7}
}
```

Although `\en{}` works fine for the author and title fields, it fails to work with the URL field, creating the reference as follows:

```
MSRC Team. «A proactive approach to more secure code». (Ιούλ. 2019), διεύθν.:
%5ἓν%7Βηττπς://μσρς-βλογ.μιςροσοφτ.ςομ/2019/07/16/α-προαςτιvε-αππροαςη-
το-μορε-σεςυρε-ςοδε/%7Δ.
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,greek,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{chapters/bibliography.bib}

% typeset short english phrases
\newcommand{\en}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\selectlanguage{greek}

\begin{document}
    Κείμενο \en{Text}\cite{microsoft-memory-safety-errors}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: that can't work. Url is handled with rather special code. Show a complete example so that one can test solutions.

Comment: In particular, please tell us whether you load the `url` or (better still) the `xurl` package.

Comment: @Mico Yes I am loading `url` with the `hyphens` option. I tried to substitute it with `hyperref` but to no avail.

Comment: Make a *small*  but *complete*  example. So remove unneeded packages but add the document body.  Do not use \include.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am a beginner in latex so I provided you with every package that is imported because I don't know what all of them do and how they may affect/cause my problem. How can I avoid using `\include` to include my chapters in the main? Is `\input` the appropriate command?

Comment: you have a problem with a bib entry. You only need a \cite command to demontrate it. All the other text is quite probably irrelevant. At best copy everything in a test folder and then start to remove things until you have a small example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have updated the question to a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For entries which are fully english, consider to use the langid field and the language option of biblatex to switch the language. This will also translate for example the date. The effect can be seen in the first entry.

If you prefer to switch to english only for special fields with your `\en` command: don't use it for an url, that will simply break.

url's should typically always be in a latin/ascii so the easiest is to switch the encoding in `\UrlFont`.

I used article as class to get everything on one page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,greek,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage[style=ieee,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

% typeset short english phrases
\newcommand{\en}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\usepackage{xurl} %more break points 
\renewcommand\UrlFont{\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily}


\begin{document}

    \url{https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2019/07/16/a-proactive-approach-to-more-secure-code/}
    
    Κείμενο \en{Text}
    
    \cite{microsoft-memory-safety-errors}
    \cite{microsoft-memory-safety-errors-var}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

used bib entries

```
@online{microsoft-memory-safety-errors,
    author={MSRC Team},
    title={A proactive approach to more secure code},
    url={https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2019/07/16/a-proactive-approach-to-more-secure-code/},
    year={2019},
    month={7},
    langid={english}
}

@online{microsoft-memory-safety-errors-var,
    author={\en{MSRC Team}},
    title={\en{A proactive approach to more secure code}},
    url={https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2019/07/16/a-proactive-approach-to-more-secure-code/},
    year={2019},
    month={7},
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! So, since I prefer the second variant, the renewed `\UrlFont` does the job without having to use the `autolang` option on biblatex. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well good small examples make it quite easy to answer. And yes, if you prefer the second simply redefine \Urlfont.